# For Office 2016, how to always show Calendar Appointment "To" field?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I get around the fact that Outlook doesn't do autocomplete in the scheduling assistant by adding invitees via the "To" field, which does support that, before going to the scheduling assistant.

However, it is an annoyance that I have to click on the button "Invite Attendees" every time just to get that "To" field to appear at all.  I'm hoping someone knows of a setting to keep that permanently on?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is using the "New Meeting" option an option? The "To" field is open by default there.  I think the reason why it's not open for the appointments tab is because appointments are meant to be used more so for one self with the option to add people if necessary.  Meetings on the other hand, are meant to be among many people (as the word "meeting" implies), hence why the "To" line is already present for meetings.

Comment: Ah, perhaps that's the problem then.  I am just using the "new item" button on my collapsed nav panel, and this is what it defaults to.  Perhaps my question should be "how do I get Outlook to default 'new item' to be a meeting rather than an appt?"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I'm asking the wrong question... this is expected behaviour for appointments, as @timmy jim points out!  Closing and re-posting as the correct question....

Comment: If you edited your answer to be a plain statement of fact "This is expected behaviour." it may be worth choosing that as the accepted answer- this is more of a comment as it stands.

Comment: Your complaint is completely a stylistic issue; the same information is being communicated either way.  If it contains the answer, it's not "more of a comment".  It might be an answer with extra commentary, but it's an answer and not a comment nonetheless.

Comment: It wasn't a complaint as such, just a suggestion. It's completely your choice as to what to do, but if someone comes across it in a review queue (as I did); they might instead conclude it isn't an answer and instead that it *reads/appears as if it was intended as a comment*, which is what I meant to say in my first comment. So you don't think I'm arbitrarily deciding this myself- ["signatures and fluff are discouraged and fair game to be removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts), per meta. YMMV, take it or leave it :)